# I am using lint with angular2+, How can I sort the constructor parameters alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, angular, lint, tslint

I want to sort the constructor params here. I am using TSLINT with Angular9 right now. IS there any rule which can be used such as member-ordering.

```
constructor(
    // Sort these
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly _changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private readonly favoritesService: FavoritesService,
    private readonly jsonService: JsonService,
    private readonly messageService: MessageService,
    public readonly helperService: HelperService,
    public readonly dialog: MatDialog,
    public readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    //
  }
```

I am using these rules currently, but these does not sort the constructor params.

```
"member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "alphabetize": true,
        "order": [
          "private-static-field",
          "protected-static-field",
          "public-static-field",

          "private-instance-field",
          "protected-instance-field",
          "public-instance-field",

          "private-constructor",
          "protected-constructor",
          "public-constructor",

          "private-static-method",
          "protected-static-method",
          "public-static-method",

          "private-instance-method",
          "protected-instance-method",
          "public-instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want that?^^

Comment: @jBuchholz It will give a better visibility of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer to the question but I still think it's worth mentioning:

#### Do not concern yourself (too much) with the order of your constructor arguments

IMO you should not concern yourself about the order of arguments in a constructor too much - and especially not if you will never call it yourself since Angular will handle that for you.

[Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101346/what-is-best-practice-on-ordering-parameters-in-a-function) you can find an extended discussion about the topic.

Ordering might be important if you want to conform to an existing API or expose your functions publicly and want to make them more concise.
In regular functions ordering might make it easier to understand function calls or it might just feel "more natural". All of this does not apply to a constructor that no person will ever call.

#### Ordering the arguments (alphabetically) will not increase the readability of your code.

Consider the following two snippets:

```
constructor(
  private readonly router: Router,
  private readonly _changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
  private readonly favoritesService: FavoritesService,
  private readonly jsonService: JsonService,
  private readonly messageService: MessageService,
  public readonly helperService: HelperService,
  public readonly dialog: MatDialog,
  public readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) {}
```

vs.

```
constructor(
  private readonly _changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
  public readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  public readonly dialog: MatDialog,
  private readonly favoritesService: FavoritesService,
  public readonly helperService: HelperService,
  private readonly jsonService: JsonService,
  private readonly messageService: MessageService,
  private readonly router: Router,
) {}
```

Which of them is better? If any it would be the first because it keeps `private` and `public` declarations together.

#### Other ordering-options

If you insist on ordering your arguments I'd think of two possibilities

1. group related arguments (e.g. router and activatedRoute)
2. group by framework vs. own

#### TSLint

As far as I know - and tried to google in the last minutes - there is no rule that will help you with your goal - undermining my argumentation that nobody seems to have seen any need for it.

If you really do want to enforce that rule, have a look at [creating your own rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule out: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/member-ordering/

And then you can add this rule to your config:

```
"member-ordering": [
  true,
  {
    "alphabetize": true,
    "order": [
      "public-static-field",
      "public-instance-field",
      "public-constructor",
      "private-static-field",
      "private-instance-field",
      "private-constructor",
      "public-instance-method",
      "protected-instance-method",
      "private-instance-method"
    ]
  }
]
```

It does have auto-fix too.

Comment: I have updated my question with the rules I am using but no effects on constructor params.

Comment: Member-ordering does not refer to the order of constructor/function arguments, does it?

Comment: @jBuchholz yes it does not. There maybe some other rule available to achieve this.

Comment: Oh, I just saw that, of course, you are right jBuchholz. Constructor arguments are not members.